# Error building project - unable to find assemblies in the package folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget-package

I have loaded a solution developed in a older visual studio version in my local visual studio 2017. There are many reference to external dlls. When I compile the solution I get error as below despite the fact that the dll's are available under the "packages" folder in the solution. The target framework of the projects  in the solution are set to .NET Framework 4. I have .NET Framework 4.7.1 installed in my computer. I would appreciate some help on this.

[image]

**Updated** with project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{D47A4044-AC8E-49F8-AD93-9D595F594C85}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Biz</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TakstNettBiz</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation />
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StyleCopEnabled>false</StyleCopEnabled>
    <StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>false</StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'CIFastBuild|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\CIFastBuild\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\AutoMapper.3.3.0\lib\net40\AutoMapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="AutoMapper.Net4, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\AutoMapper.3.3.0\lib\net40\AutoMapper.Net4.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Castle.Core.3.2.2\lib\net40-client\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Common.Logging">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Common.Logging.2.1.2\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FluentMigrator">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\FluentMigrator.1.4.0.0\lib\40\FluentMigrator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Magnum">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Magnum.2.1.3\lib\NET40\Magnum.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MassTransit">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\MassTransit.2.9.9\lib\net40\MassTransit.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MassTransit.Transports.MSMQ">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\MassTransit.MSMQ.2.9.9\lib\net40\MassTransit.Transports.MSMQ.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.Edm.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.OData.5.2.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\lib\Microsoft Windows Identity Foundation 3.5\Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.1.8.0.0\lib\net35-full\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.1.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.2.1.0.3\lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.6\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Ninject.3.2.2.0\lib\net40\Ninject.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="RestSharp">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\RestSharp.104.2.0\lib\net4\RestSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Services.Client" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization">
      <RequiredTargetFramework>3.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Spatial, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\System.Spatial.5.2.0\lib\net40\System.Spatial.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DataVisualization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.2.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="WebActivatorEx">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\WebActivatorEx.2.0.5\lib\net40\WebActivatorEx.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

Comment: How does `csproj` look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski updated description with the csproj file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `hintpath` of your project did not point to the right dll path of your `packages` folder under the solution folder.

If the `csproj` exists under the proejct folder while the packages folder is on one above folder of the file, then the error happens.

You should change `..\..\` to `..\`. Use the right path.

Or try this command under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

```
update-package -reinstall
```

to reinstall all the nuget packages.

## **Answer from the Customer**

embarrassingly enough the whole issue was with the solution path where my solution was located in my local computer. I had a long path including a folder having two words as well. After trying everything else I moved the solution folder to C:\temp folder and the issue was no longer there. The error showed in VS was quite misleading. What a waist of time. Thank you for your efforts !

Comment: embarrassingly enough the whole issue was with the solution path where my solution was located in my local computer. I had a long path including a folder having two words as well. After trying everything else I moved the solution to the folder C:\temp and the issue was no longer there. The error showed in VS was quite misleading. What a waist of time. Thank you for your efforts !